# setInterval javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5

O seguinte código funciona como a função ´setTimeout´ (acontecendo apenas uma vez e não se repetindo), já tentei vários jeitos e não consegui, se alguém puder me ajudar, já agradeço.

```
    function girar(){           
        var bola = document.getElementById("ball");     
        window.xvel = 10;       
        setInterval(function(){                     
                    window.xvel = parseFloat(window.xvel) + parseFloat("10");                       
        }, 500);            
        bola.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + window.xvel + "deg)";      
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa alterar a rotação **dentro** do *callback* do `setInterval`:

```
function girar(){           
    var bola = document.getElementById("ball");     
    window.xvel = 10;       
    setInterval(function(){                     
        window.xvel = parseFloat(window.xvel) + parseFloat("10");   
        bola.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + window.xvel + "deg)"; 
    }, 500);                      
}
```

[Exemplo com bola quadrada](http://jsfiddle.net/bfavaretto/9jm72/)

Comment: Obrigado, em ajudou muito.

Comment: +1 pela bola quadrada