# setInterval não repete

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte problema:

Na minha página, o `setInterval` não repete, tentei de várias formas, até simplificar no modo abaixo para ver se funcionaria, mas mesmo assim ele não repete, está trabalhando como um `setTimeout`.

```
function teste(){
    $("#teste").append("a");
 }
 var x = setInterval(teste(),1000);
```

Comment: No `setInterval` retire o parêntesis de `teste`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [setInterval javascript não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23861/setinterval-javascript-n%c3%a3o-funciona)

Answer (score 9):

O problema é que você está passando o resultado da função `teste` para o `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(teste(), 1000);
// 'teste' é executado, e, como ele não retorna nada, essa linha é equivalente a:
setInterval(undefined, 1000);
```

Enfim, para arrumar, passe a referência para a função `teste` para o `setInterval`. Código arrumado:

```
function teste(){
    $("#teste").append("a");
}
var x = setInterval(teste, 1000); // <-- sem parênteses
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf60hsap/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: vale a pena salientar? http://jsfiddle.net/qj57Lffz/