# JavaScript SetInterval não funcionando... em que errei?

Tags: javascript

Como podem ver no meu código abaixo, eu precisei transformar minha imagem em link por JavaScript ao invés de usar o método simples por HTML (por razões específicas), porém eu preciso que leve um intervalo de 3 segundos para a função arrancar, mas não consegui... sabem me dizer no que eu errei?

```
<a name="subir">aqui</a>
<div style="height: 1000px; width: 100%;"></div>
<img src="next.png" id="cima">

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('cima').addEventListener('click', function() {
 location.href = '#subir'}, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Na verdade só usou a função errada. Primeiro veja a documentação do [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) e depois verifique se isso te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23861/57801

Comment: Você tem razão, sintaxe errada! como falou o @dvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sintaxe errada. Não use `setInterval` (irá executar o código infinitas vezes), use `setTimeout` (executa só 1 vez):

```js
document.getElementById('cima').addEventListener('click', function() {
   setTimeout("location.href = '#subir'", 3000);
});
```

```html
<a name="subir">aqui</a>
<div style="height: 1000px; width: 100%;"></div>
<img src="next.png" id="cima">
```

Comment: Não porque setInterval é contínuo, enquanto setTimeout só executa 1 vez.

Comment: Poxa, exatamente! Obrigado. Já volto pra selecionar como a resposta correta :)

Comment: @Everson Obg Everson.